# HighlightJS highlights keywords in names for SQL. How do I tune the parser?

Tags: javascript, highlight.js

For example, file names such as retail-sample.xls has the word sample highlihgted as a keyword.

Is there any way to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is an option for you, however, HighlightJS should work with any HTML tags instead of the usual `<pre><code>`. This should allow you to highlight filenames in your markup while still preserving the styles for SQL.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/25maz9x4/